# Boost::asio Asynchronous TCP read terminates before timeout. Could it be something related to Windows imposed TCP/IP limits?

Tags: c++, boost, tcp, boost-asio, winsock

I am following the timeout example from Boost Official website: 
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/timeouts/blocking_tcp_client.cpp

Just sticking the main from the link:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  try
  {
    if (argc != 4)
    {
      std::cerr << "Usage: blocking_tcp <host> <port> <message>\n";
      return 1;
    }

    client c;
    c.connect(argv[1], argv[2], boost::posix_time::seconds(10));

    boost::posix_time::ptime time_sent =
      boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time();

    c.write_line(argv[3], boost::posix_time::seconds(10));

    for (;;)
    {
      std::string line = c.read_line(boost::posix_time::seconds(10));

      // Keep going until we get back the line that was sent.
      if (line == argv[3])
        break;
    }

    boost::posix_time::ptime time_received =
      boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time();

    std::cout << "Round trip time: ";
    std::cout << (time_received - time_sent).total_microseconds();
    std::cout << " microseconds\n";
  }
  catch (std::exception& e)
  {
    std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I can see that for timeouts beyond a specific limit (around 40s), the read_line() simply terminates. I tested with a dummy target which responds after a predefine time. I am sending some APIs over network and the application on the other end returns 0 or 1 after specified time. The timeout works perfectly till 40sec.

Could it have to do with Windows TCP registry timeout limits? In Wireshark logs I see multiple packets containing same payload from the client (sending API) right and some duplicate ACKs before termination. This is on Windows.

Comment: What do you mean by "terminates"? Does it return an empty string?

Comment: If you truly suspect this, you can access the native handle and use the correct windows API's to manually change timeouts on the raw socket in ::asio. However, I'd strongly advise that you reconsider your logic. Leaving code locked up for over 40 seconds at any given point gives terrible user experience and also makes you wait literal eons (in CPU time) before your software can do anything (adjust to new conditions etc).

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Boost error code changes from would_block and it tries to throw an exception. error code is 121. I checked and found its a very generic "system error"

Comment: @TechnikEmpire Thanks.  Actually I send Driver APIs to a remote embedded machine which executes them and sends me success or failure back. When I am doing stress testing, these APIs are bound to take time and return after a minute or so. API running server/target is very simple and has Light Weight IP stack running over it. I am guessing that it has to do with Windows Registry settings like MAX_RETRANSMISSION or CLOSE_WAIT.

Comment: If that's the case and it's a barrier, consider changing from long-standing persistent connections to something else, with asio you could easily run a lightweight client and sever in one package so it's acting more in a p2p manner than just one way client->server, have your remote API open a connection back to the requesting client after it has taken its sweet time processing and return the result, or go UDP.